# Как перевести HTML в PDF скриптом?

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, конвертер

Сразу прошу не отправлять в гугль, в основном там предлагаются он-лайн сервисы, только пару видел с апи, который требует денег за полную функциональность.

Он-лайн мне малоинтересен, поскольку моя страничка собирается в ходе выполнения js-скрипта, ссылка на нее даст нужного отображения.

Желательно услышать мнение людей, которые реально решали такую проблему. js или php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTMLDOC](http://www.htmldoc.org/)

> HTMLDOC converts Hyper-Text Markup Language ("HTML") files and web pages into indexed HTML, Adobe® PostScript®, or Adobe Portable Document Format ("PDF") files.

[TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)

> TCPDF is a FLOSS PHP class for generating PDF documents.

Answer (score 4):

Софт **HTML2PDF Pilot**

Скрипт на PHP называется **fpdf**

Comment: Пожалуйста, внимательно читайте вопрос -- меня не интересует приложение, тем более под винду. Скрипт, только скрипт!

Comment: написал же:
>Скрипт на PHP называется fpdf

Comment: http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: не то.
разработчик сам об этом пишет:
19. Can I convert an HTML page to PDF with FPDF?
Not real-world pages. But a GPL C utility does exist, htmldoc, which allows to do it and gives good results: http://www.htmldoc.org 
(я уже на этой ссылке...)

Comment: Все то, лучше ищите http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/index.php

А то он пишет зачем создал и как пользоваться

Comment: http://www.fpdf.org/en/download.php - скачать

Answer (score 3):

**[mpdf](http://mpdf1.com/)** Нормально поддерживает кириллицу

Answer (score 3):

Из всех библиотек, которые я перепробовал, лучше [**wkhtmltopdf**](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) найти не смог. Данная библиотека использует **[qtwebkit](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit)** для рендера PDF. А это означает, что вы можете использовать для генерации `PDF` последние плюшки **`CSS3`** (градиенты, тени) и **`JavaScript`** (т.е. страницы собранные динамически тоже будут корректно генерироваться)

Answer (score 1):

Решение на PHP. Расписано использование библиотеки Dompdf

[Конвертируем HTML в PDF](http://phpdesigner.in.ua/php/konvertiruem-html-v-pdf/)

Answer (score 0):

Dompdf давно не поддерживается. У нас, если HTML был чуть больше чем надо, сразу происходила ошибка генерации. И так у многих, судя по форумам, решить ее не удалось. Сейчас пользуемся генерацией [HTML в PDF по API pdf4b.ru](https://pdf4b.ru) Пользуемся бесплатно, просто ссылаемся на сайте на них все.